# Delete all lines between two specific line numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, with-statement

I need to delete all lines bewtwen to other  lines, based on the line numbers.
In this file.py, how could i delete all files betwen the 2º and the 6º line ?

file :

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

With this code i can delete all lines above and/or bellow of an specific line. But i cannot

code :

```
with open('file.py', 'r') as fin:
    data = fin.read().splitlines(True)
    with open('ab.py', 'w') as fout:
        fout.writelines(data[2:])
```

I tried this second code, where i can delete only 1 specific line ( when i tried to delete more then 1 it didn't work very well)

```
del_line1 = 1   
with open("file.py","r") as textobj:
    list = list(textobj)   
del list[del_line1 - 1]    
with open("file.py","w") as textobj:
   for n in list:
        textobj.write(n)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easier than expected.

```
dellist = [3, 4, 7] #numbers of the lines to be deleted

with open('data.txt') as inpf:
    with open('out.txt', 'w') as of:
        for i, line in enumerate(inpf):
            if i+1 not in dellist: #i+1 because i starts from 0
                of.write(line)
```

You read each line, and if the line number is not in the list of prohibited lines, the line is written to another file.

So assuming your original input, the code above gives:

```
1
2
5
6
8
9
10
```

Note: here I called the file `data.txt`, it's better to use the `.py` extension for files with python code inside only.